# Why is contactDelegate not being set?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm getting the following warning from the line

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'PlayLevel *__strong'

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size level:(int)level{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        _level = level;
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
        self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Not at all sure what's causing it. 
This is what my header looks like:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface PlayLevel : SKScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size level:(int)level;

@end
```

Any idea's what's causing it? I kind of need a contactDelegate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declarer on your class interface (inside <>) that your class implement the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to add the delegate reference in your header file. For example if we are using the `UINavigationController` delegates we add `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` in the header file. Similary you will have to add the contact delegate

Answer (score 0):

In your header where you declare that `PlayLevel` extends `SKScene`, you need to also declare that it implements the `SKContactDelegate` interface like so:

```
@interface PlayLevel : SKScene <SKPhysicsContactDelegate>
```